# Wcf Service List<> parameter .Add method do not appear

Tags: wcf, list, parameters

I Have a WCF service thant work fine, I consume it from the client.. I want to pass List<> as parameter and i have this lines

```
[OperationContract]    
void Insert(List<PersonList> person);

[DataContract]    
public class PersonList    
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Person> Persons{ get; set; }    
}
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
     [DataMember]
     public  string Name
}
```

From the Client

```
PersonList per = new PersonList();    
Person pp = new person();    
pp.Name = "aaa";    
per.Persons.Add(pp);
```

ADD Does not Exists?
What I am missing?

Comment: did you added using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; in client side ?? Try with per.Persons.ToList().Add(pp);

Answer (score 0):

If your client is auto-generated from Visual Studio, you can choose if your collections are implemented as arrays or lists. I'm guessing it's arrays. Go to configure service reference and chose list as default collection type instead of arrays.